# ForEach over an array of protocol implementations?

Tags: swift, foreach, swiftui

I'm starting to learn SwiftUI, and so I decided to write a simple password manager as a learning exercise.  I've defined a `protocol` with the common attributes in my passwords:

```
protocol Secret: Codable {
    
    var id: String { get set }
    var name: String { get set }
    var createdDate: Date { get set }
    
    var favorite: Bool { get set }
    
    var category: SecretCategory { get set }
    
    var notes: String { get set }
    
    init(_ id: String, name: String)
    init(_ id: String, name: String, favorite: Bool)

}
```

Then, I've defined a couple of Swift `struct`s that implement this `protocol` and define the properties of various types of secrets:

```
struct LoginSecret: Secret, Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var createdDate: Date = Date()
    
    var favorite: Bool = false
    
    var category: SecretCategory = .login
    
    var notes: String = ""
    
    var username: String = ""
    var encryptedPassword: String = ""
    
    var websiteURLs: [String] = []
    
    init(_ id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
    
    init(_ id: String, name: String, favorite: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.favorite = favorite
    }
}
```

...and...

```
struct BankAccountSecret: Secret, Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var createdDate: Date = Date()
    
    var favorite: Bool = false
    
    var category: SecretCategory = .bankAccounts
    
    var notes: String = ""
    
    var bankName: String = ""
    var nameOnAccount: String = ""
    var routingNumber: String = ""
    var accountNumber: String = ""
    
    var swift: String = ""
    var iban: String = ""
    
    var encryptedPIN: String = ""
    
    var branchPhoneNumber: String = ""
    var branchAddress: Address = Address()
    
    init(_ id: String, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
    
    init(_ id: String, name: String, favorite: Bool) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.favorite = favorite
    }
}
```

These work just fine, and I'm able to Encode/Decode values in JSON for display later.  However, now I'm working on my SwiftUI code.  I want to display each item in a `List`, iterating over an `Array` of `Secret` objects using SwiftUI's `ForEach`.  My code looks like this:

```
struct SecretsListView: View {

    @State    
    var secrets: [Secret]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
               ForEach(secrets) { secret in
                  <snip>
               }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

However, when I compile I get an error saying...

```
Value of protocol type 'Secret' cannot conform to 'Identifiable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

Is there no way to iterate over an array of `Secret` objects?  Is there a different way to accomplish this?  Is this issue specific to SwiftUI's `ForEach`?  Should I use the standard Swift `Array` `forEach` method instead?  Any guidance you can provide is greatly appreciated.  I've worked with Swift and UIKit for a while, but SwiftUI is new and I want to make sure I'm developing for the framework correctly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, only `SwiftUI.ForEach` requires the `Identifiable` conformance, `Array.forEach` does not require it.

There are several other initialisers of `ForEach` though that don't require your model type to conform to `Identifiable`.

You could use `init(_ data: Data, id: KeyPath<Data.Element, ID>, content: @escaping (Data.Element) -> Content)` for instance (assuming that `ID` conforms to `Hashable`, which `Secret.id` does, since it's a `String`).

```
ForEach(secrets, id: \.id) { secret in
    <snip>
}
```

Another solution would be passing the indices of the array to `ForEach`, then you could use `ForEach(secrets.indices)`, but since you have a `Hashable` property on `Secret` that you can use as the `id`, that's a the previous one is a better solution.

Comment: Perfect!!  I knew there was something small I was missing.  That worked perfectly!